# Rendering glitch, navigation links overlap new answers notification

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Currently using Firefox 3.6.3 and I haven't tried this on other browsers, but it might be a bit hard to catch. However, as per the screen shot, the navigation links are overlapping the notification that appears when there are new answers.

[image]

Comment: i'm looking into this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have put in a fix, it will be in the next deployment.